# Long data format for Mixed linear modeling

Tags: bayesian, multiple-regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, stan

I  have a data set from an experiment with two conditions: a control condition, and a testing condition. It's an experiment performed in pairs. Each condition was undertaken by 20 pairs of subjects (total 40 pairs).

I want to compare outcomes between the conditions with Bayesian modeling.

How do I write the data in long format? Should I have two models to compare and hence two sets of long data, or should I do this with one set of long data format for both conditions?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately this does not seen like a question about statistics!

Answer (score 1):

I do not completely follow your question. Are you using a program like HLM 7 that requires you to have multiple datasets?

Also, what makes your experiment appropriate for mixed linear modeling?  Do you mean long as in longitudinal format?

If you are asking how to structure your data for use in a mixed model, you use a stacked format where a row corresponds to an observation at a given time point. So if you have a group with 4 observations over time, that group would have 4 rows associated with it. One for each time point.

Comment: my data is from an eye tracking experiment.As far as I  understand it fits a linear mixed model.Could it be possible to write you an email with details ?

Comment: Yes I meant as longitudunal format for a repeated measure experiment for hypothesis testing.I am not sure to use model comparison or BIC for hypothesis testing.

Comment: @mashedpoteto send me a private messages and I will forward you my email

Comment: is there an option to sent a private message?